# Simplex minimization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

I've noticed that my OR book doesn't talk much about minimization with Simplex. I've read some things online but it's still a bit messy in my head. If I have greater or equal restraints, if I set min Z = max -Z then it feels like I'll end up with an unlimited problem. If I have a mix of greater than or equal or less than or equal to restraints will I be able to solve min Z using the max -Z technique?

Minimization seems like a bit of a mess to me with Simplex. Why can't I just use additional variables $y_1,y_2,\text{...},y_n\geq0$ and subtract them from greater than or equal restraints to obtain equality restraints?

Comment: Quote: "If I have greater or equal restraints, if I set min Z = max -Z then it feels like I'll end up with an unlimited problem." In some cases it is possible,-independently if it is a min-problem or a max-problem.

Comment: Why can't I just use additional variables $y_1,y_2,...,y_n≥0$ and subtract them from greater than or equal restraints to obtain equality restraints? You have to to that in any case if you apply the simplex algorithm. These additional variables are called **surplus variables**.

Comment: Or more commonly, slack variables.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why you are confused many people seem to use different approaches online .
One way you can work is this: **turn the minimization problem into standard form**. That is :

- replacing the objective function z by -z and
- asking for maximisation while at the same time you make sure you have constraints in the form of
  $a_ix_i \leq b_i$

---

But I have seen people solving it as such as well :
Keep the objective function as it is and apply those rules:

- For the pivot column you look for the most positive (instead of the most negative) coefficient in the line corresponding to the objective function
- compute the min ratio as usual